# What data is submitted with a form?

Tags: http-post, submit, forms, http-get

When html form is submitted by using method POST, what data is submitted. I know that the name and value of the 'input' are submitted, but apart from that, is there anything else that gets through? In those terms, is there a difference for using method GET?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

POST - submits data for processing to a source

GET - requests data from a source

You should read more on those here: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_httpmethods.asp

Comment: Thanks Kyle. 
There it states "Note that query strings (name/value pairs) is sent in the HTTP message body of a POST request"; so I guess that means names and values and nothing else.